# PHP AJAX POST VALUE

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

how to post value of checkbox 
when it checked or uncheked

I have Code

```
    $("#check").click(function(){`var data = {
               kd_material:$("#kd_material").val(),
               check : $(this).val('1') ? $(this).val("1") : $(this).val("0")
              };

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url : "<?php echo base_url().'ms_select/select_id_material_koreksi_cek'?>",             
      data: data,
      success: function(msg){
         $('#div-gudang').html(msg);
      }
    });
 }); `
```

Comment: Do you really have a backtick before `var data`?

Comment: You have ` in your code before var

Comment: And one at the end as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the isChecked property of the checkbox and send it.

```
$("#check").click(function(){`var data = {
                   kd_material:$("#kd_material").val(),
                   check : $(this).is(":checked") 
};
```

The value true/false would be sent to the server.

But if you want to send 1/0 you can do it like this.

```
check : $(this).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).val('1')` doesn't return a boolean. It sets the value of `$(this)` to `1` and returns `$(this)` for chaining.

To tell whether the box is checked, use `this.checked` or `$(this).is(":checked")`. So it should be:

```
check: this.checked ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#check").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':cheked'))
    {
       var chkValue = 1;
    }
    else
    {
       var chkValue = 0;
    }
});
```

Use chkValue as a variable in `ajax() data` like:

```
data: {
   value : chkValue
}
```